# Access a viewControllers View

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am trying to get to grips with programmatically configuring views. I have a UIViewController and want to add a UIButton to its view.

Well, I created the button:

```
UIButton *newViewButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(baseX + viewPlusX, baseY + viewPlusY, viewWidth, viewHeight)];
[newViewButton setTitle:@"View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[newViewButton setTag:(int)key];
[newViewButton addTarget:myViewController action:@selector(viewButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

but when trying to add it to the view

```
[myViewController.view addSubview:newViewButton];
```

I get the error

```
error: expected ':' before":" token
```

any clue what I am doing wrong

regards

Comment: You should really start to accept answers that helped you out. You accept an answer by clicking the checkmark at the top-left of the helpful answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@selector(viewButton:sender)` should read `@selector(viewButton:sender:)`

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
[myViewController.view addSubview:newViewButton];
```

Comment: Hi Ole, actually I mistyped my cry for help (just updated it). This is how I've got it and where I get the error as above ...

Comment: it seems the "myViewController.view" reference causes the error. An NSLog reveals error "accessing unknown 'view' class method". 
Don't understand this since myViewController is of type  UIViewController.